# Sharepoint list have german date convert into Monthnumber

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, modern-experience, sharepoint-list

I have a German client sahrepoint list and I want to convert month from date column in number.

Like Month and Year in German:

[image]

Want to Extract Month and year in separate column for further calculation in Number.

When I try to use:

`=TEXT([Date1],"mm")`

This is Giving garbage value(`#value`).

Answer (score 0):

If `Date1` has a data type of **Date and Time** then try using below:

```
=TEXT([Date1],"mmmm")
```

It should return complete name of the month.

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Return your calculated field as **Single line of text**.

**official documentation**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do via create multiple columns .

In First column(M1) Extract month part form the string

```
=LEFT([Month],INT(FIND(" ",[Month])-1))
```

Then Second column(M2) Extract Year part

```
=RIGHT([Month],LEN([Month])-INT(FIND(" ",[Month])))
```

Finally concat those columns into Date Column

```
=CONCATENATE("01","/",[M2],"/",[M3])
```

If anyone have any other way ,please share your thought.